# Is there a way where I could put a line break for each data it displays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have this array and I can already display it on the screen. I'm wondering if I can put a line break for each of the data it displays.

```
{
      name: "cartItems",
      label: "Product Name",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          // console.log(value, "cartItems");
          return value.map(
            (value) =>
              value.name +
              " (" +
              value.color +
              ") - " +
              " Qty:" +
              value.quantity +
              ","
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

As of now, it displays in one line like this:

Item name (item color) - Qty: 1
Item name (item color) - Qty: 2
Item name (item color) - Qty: 2

I wanted to somehow display it like this:

```
Item name (item color) - Qty: 1
Item name (item color) - Qty: 2
Item name (item color) - Qty: 2
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `\n`

```
          return value.map(
            (value) =>
              value.name +
              " (" +
              value.color +
              ") - " +
              " Qty:" +
              value.quantity +
              "," + 
              "\n"
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
return value.map((value) => `${value.name} (${value.color}) - Qty: ${value.quantity}, 
`);
```